# How to get instance of a Class in another Application

Tags: android

I have the follow question.

In my application I need to get instance of a Class of another application.

I need to get an instance of the Store Class of the stock Android email client.

I have seen that in the source code of the Android stock email client this is done by
calling:

```
Store store = Store.getInstance(mAccount.getStoreUri(this), getApplication(), null);
```

getInstance() is `public synchronized static`

How can I do the same from inside my Application?

Comment: IDK much, but this is refered to as [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do the same from inside my Application?

You don't, for blindingly obvious security reasons. One application cannot randomly mess with another application's objects.